# How to add custom status code in spring data rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, http-status-code-404, spring-data

I'm doing Spring Data REST. Following the simple example for getting started described here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/ I have a question I'm thinking about.

The query "curl http://localhost:8080/people/search/findByLastName?name=Baggins" will return HTTP Status 200, (OK) even if no results were found (the json will be {}). How can I make it return HTTP status 404 instead (when no result were found).

The documentation only mentions the standard status codes: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources

Comment: You are doing a search and an empty result is perfectly valid. Now when you would do a GET to a specific resource then a 404 would make sense not in this case (IMHO).

Comment: Valid opinion for sure, but it still doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is not a good idea to return 404 when you have no results. You should return status `204 No Content`.

You can create a custom exception annotated with `ResponseStatus` (I'd suggest this approach):

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
     public class NoElementsFoundException extends Exception {
}
```

Whenever you have no elements to return you throw this exception.

You can also play with `HttpServletResponse`.